# Animate only a part of an element

Tags: jquery-ui, animation

how can I animate only a part of an element?

I show/hide a div using jquery-ui's `show` method but I'd like to start/end the animation from/to a given height of the element.

My dev website can be seen here (link removed). When clicking on the 'Contact' button the contact page shows up or hides if it's already open. Since I couldn't find how to starts my animation from a given height I added a fixed button when it's closed, but when the contact button of the contact page overlaps the fixed button when it's closing...

Any help welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looking for something like this??

http://jsfiddle.net/rlemon/F6Efp/8/

You can also add any fade or whatever effects. This is using a single button to animate both open and close. You could also attach a attribute to the button tag to define it's current state.